# Proof that the composition of two inversion with the same center is a homothety

Tags: geometry, mobius-transformation

It is asking me for the inversion of two concentric circles, but I just have no idea how to solve this, I've been stuck for a while

Comment: Write them in coordiantes: you'll obtain two functions that depend on three parameters (the coordinates of the centre and the two radii). Computing the composition is then a matter of sums, products and divisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a point $P$ on the plane, within distance $d$ from the common center. The first inversion takes $P$ to a point $Q$ within distance $d'=r_1^2/d$ from the center. The second inversion takes $Q$ to a new point $R$ a distance $d''=r_2^2/d'=r_2^2d/r_1^2$ from the center. By definition, the center, $P$, $Q$ and $R$ are aligned. The composition takes thus $P$ to a point on $OP$ within a distance $d''=kd$ from the center, where $k=r_2^2/r_1^2$. This is a homothety by definition.